# Any libraries to resolve a large set of ip addresses in mysql table to country names or continents?

Tags: mysql, ip-address

Every time a request is serviced on my website, a record is inserted into a 2 column mysql table with the ip address the request was serviced from and the datetime of the execution.

I wanted a high level estimation of where my users are coming from (Ex. 50% from North America, 20% from Asia, 20% from Europe, 10% other)  Are you aware of any libraries that can resolve this large set of ip addresses to the names of countries or continents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MaxMind's GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) has bindings for a number of programming languages.